# Runtime error when push_back to a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, int>*> *v;
    pair<int, int> *x = new pair<int, int>();
    cin >> x->first >> x->second;
    v->push_back(x);
    cout << v->size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code get run-time error? I dont understand. All I do is appending a pair pointer to a vector of pair pointer.

Comment: I don't do much C++, but I don't think `v` is initialised, because it's a pointer the object isn't created implicitly. `vector<pair<int, int>*> *v = new vector<pair<int, int>*>();` should work. This would explain why you're getting a segfault - you're trying to access a null pointer `v`.

Comment: ... shit, basic mistake. Im so dump. Yea me too, Im kind switching to js which is more free to create a new object without initiallizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Vector definition should be (this resolves the run-time error):

```
vector<pair<int, int>*> v;
```

Second, you don't release the memory of the new pair. This will solve that issue too:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> v;
pair<int, int> x{ 0,0 };
```

A vector of pairs, rather than a vector of pair-pointers. On the other hand: If it necessary to use a vector of pointers, smart pointers is a better choice.

Comment: Im so dump. Thank you.